# Link Species Names to Wiki

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to configure this StackExchange so that when someone uses the name of a species, a Wikipedia or Gardening Stack Exchange wiki article is linked? It would enhance the usability of the forum.

Comment: Now this is interesting.  I like this idea!  Of course, us answering should include that although I know I am guilty to not always do so.  I'd also like to see the ID whys...serrated edges, opposite/alternate, simple ID markers.  Be good for us knee jerk IDer's as well as OP's learning ID.  Nice idea David.

Answer (score 3):

I understand what you mean,  by just typing a name in and it popping up the blue link to just go ahead and get right to it,  but it really wouldnt be nessasary, you could just post the link or tell someone to go to the link which takes no time at all.  To have to go back in the programming and set that up and put the commands in would have no relevance.

Its a good idea though.